# Avoid equality constraints - Only lower bound and upper bound - Quadratic Programmering

Tags: matrices, optimization, optimal-control, quadratic-programming, upper-lower-bounds

The quadratic programming objective function for MATLAB and Octave is:

$$J_{min} = \frac{1}{2}x^THx + x^Tq$$

and the constraints are:

$$lb <= x <= ub$$
$$Ax = b$$

In this case, I want to use the qp-command from Octave because I don't have MATLAB on my computer. The qp-command differes from MATLAB's quadprog command, but the results are the same.

The command qp:

```
[x, obj, info, lambda] = qp (x0, H, q, A, b, lb, ub)
```

[Octave - 25.2 Quadratic Programming](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Quadratic-Programming.html)

**Question:**

I only want lower bounds and upper bounds constraints on vector $x$. The command need to have a value of vector $b$ and matrix $A$, which I don't have in my case. Can I say that the command should then be:

```
[x, obj, info, lambda] = qp (x0, H, q, I, Ix, lb, ub)
```

if I want to avoid setting any equality constraints? I want to set value of $b = Ix$ and just set $A = I$ to the identity matrix, and only focus on lower bound limit and upper bound limit.

What do I need to set $x_0$ to? The past $x$?

Does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have equality constraints, you set them to [] to indicate this.

$x_0$ is your best guess, but it has to be a feasible guess. Most often it doesn't help much to warm-start with a guess unless it is very close to the optimal one, so you simply set it to [] and the solver will cold-start.

Comment: Thanks! Can I set $x_0$ to a constant or does $x_0$ need to be updated as the last computed $x$? Edit: I saw now that I can set $x_0$ as [ ] too. I think I will do that.

Comment: Is it good to set the predict horizon equal to the control horizon? I have build a .m file when I use QP. If I set predict horizon equal to control horizon, then my results is getting better. Better tracking and the trajectories goes to the reference faster.

Comment: Good compared to what? The first choice is typically to have them the same. If that for some reason doesn't work out (solver is slow to handle many inputs, but we need long horizon to see effect, then one might start to complicate matters with different horizons etc)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Well, I will start with Nc = Np at the beginning. This is the first time I do linear MPC. Quite interesting may I say. Is nonlinear MPC used as well as linear MPC?

Comment: Yes, but much less.

Comment: I have read some articles about nlmpc and those controllers seems to be difficult. I only focus on simple controllers, even if they requires a lot of computations. For me, a basic MPC is quite easy if a solver is available. My question is if it's possible to use QP-solver for a on-line linearized model? Or do I need to use another solver? My idea is: Modeling -> on-line linearizing -> on-line discrete transform -> on-line augmented state space model -> QP-solving for limited inputs signals.

Comment: Most nonlinear MPC approaches boil down to linearizations of some sort. It's just a matter of whether you linearize at current state and then solve QPs, or if you send nonlinear prediction model to solver, and the solver then linearizes when it performs its nonlinear solver iterations. Your suggested approach is basically nonlinear MPC 1.0, as it is the obvious approach.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I should learn nonlinear MPC 1.0 too because I already know how to linearize a SS-model with jacobian.

Comment: This is a curious question: Have you implement MPC controller for a robotic system? Normaly I have heard that MPC is most used for slow system such as heat and fluid. The nowadays computers are today very fast and I wonder if it's possible to have MPC on a robotic arm or something like that? Instead using feedback linearizion which have a weakness for zero dynamics. Lyapunov Control law migth be an alterantive if MPC not suits fast systems with modern PC.

Comment: MPC = slow systems is something from the past. I was in a grading committee last year where they ran MPC at 10000Hz.